# Highest common factor of integers which are the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, divisibility, prime-factorization, gcd-and-lcm

If  $a=-b \in \mathbb{Z}, $

Then $hcf(a, b)=|a|=|b|$,  right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the highest factor of a number is always the number itself (number/number = 1), meaning that if you have 2 numbers *a*, *b* so that *a* = *b*, their highest factor will be *a* and *b* (respectively), which are equal by definition.